# Rails Submit button not working with classes on it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

Simple Rails form inside of a Modal.

***Will* Work**:
    `<%= submit_tag "New Form", :class => "waves-button-input" %>`

**Will *Not* Work:**

```
<%= submit_tag "New Form", :class => "waves-effect waves-green btn-flat waves-button-input" %>
```

I've tried doing this via `<input>` tags, submit tags, form submission POSTs etc. For some reason adding those classes break it.

For full context my form:

```
<div id="projectModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= form_tag(new_project_path, method: :get) %>
        <%= select_tag :project_type, options_for_select(Project.project_types.keys.to_a), :class => 'id_select', :id => 'secret_id'  %><br><br><br>
        <%#= text_field :client_id, %>
        <%= collection_select :project, :client_id, current_user.clients, :id, :name, :prompt => true %>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat modal-close">Cancel</a>
    <%= submit_tag "New Form", :class => "waves-button-input" %>

    <!--<input type="submit" name="commit" value="New Form" class="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat waves-button-input" data-disable-with="New Form">-->
    <!--<input type="submit" name="commit" value="New Form" class="waves-button-input" data-disable-with="New Form">-->
  </div>
</div>
```

On click all it does is change the `<i>` to color and full effect but makes 0 effort to send the data. Normally I would think turbolinks or something but since it works without the stylization I'm confused.

Comment: Show us what js you are using for this. Are you sure it has to be submit_tag?

Comment: @kolas Actually it's a materialize modal - So all I have is the model.init() - It can work with `submit_tag` OR `input_type` - As long as those classes aren't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add id to form and to submit tag

```
= form_tag(new_project_path, method: :get, id: 'formId')

= submit_tag "New Form", :class => "waves-effect waves-green btn-flat waves-button-input", form: 'formId'
```

Comment: Oh-my-god that actually fixed it. How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @DNorthrup Googled how to submit a form with button outside it :)

Comment: Interesting - Didn't know modals broke it like that, esp considering it worked without the classes. Will keep that in mind! Thanks again.